# Adding unsupported browser features with polyfills

Tags: polyfills, react-intl

I am working on an app and at the moment in the process of deploying. The app is using the feature react-intl from yahoo  [here](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) . I noticed a refernced to the polyfill

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=fetch,Promise,Array.from,Array.prototype.find,Array.prototype.includes,String.prototype.startsWith,String.prototype.includes,Math.sign,Intl.~locale.en,Intl.~locale.id,Intl.~locale.ru,Intl.~locale.fr&unknown=polyfill"></script>
```

And i was told its to add the feature to the browsers that do not support them. So far this works on all the devices we tested. I phone, android devices etc. However, this feature fails on ipod devices. Regardless of the ios version, the feature is not recognise on all ipod devices i tested as a result our app is failing. Please why is it that other devices iphones, androids etc supported this feature and only ipod doesn't. Did anyone had similar issue with polyfills on mobile devices ? How do i make ipod devices support this feature like the others? What am i doing wrong with the referenced ? Any help would be appreciated.